# SSRS individual row selection

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I am trying to build a report and I have created a dataset called `ChargesData`. This contains data from my Charges table which stores information about what charges belong to which utility used. Ex: Transformer allowance  is $0.80 per kVA, or Transmission charges $2.45 per kW etc etc.

I want to be able to use a specific charge for a specific `textbox` in my report. The only ways I know of right now on how to do this is to either create a dataset with a unique sql query or perhaps add a `parameter`. Is there a different way to do this? Could I put a `parameter` on the `textbox` indicating which charge id belongs with the tag then have the field expression show the correct charge?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, what you want to look at is a filter expression. You can add filter expressions to tables and groups allowing you to show only data for specific conditions. Typically you would want to add a parameter and use it in the filter expression so that the user can change what data is shown.

You can read more about filters at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633648.aspx

Comment: This is a step in the right direction. I don't want the user to be able to select the charge, I'd only want them to select their account then display the related charge and amounts so if the Transformer Allowance charge is linked, it will automatically populate the charge box with the right value. I'm going to try this and report back if the answer worked